# Sort rows of a 2d array by a column of values with negative values first, then sort by absolute values descending

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, array-multisort

I have an array like this:

```php
[
    ['array-5', 0],
    ['array-4', 0],
    ['array-1',-1],
    ['array-3', 2],
    ['array-2', 3]
]
```

I want to sort this in PHP so that negative numbers are ordered before positive numbers, and if the sign is the same, the magnitude (more negative or more positive) has precedence.

For the example above, the desired output would be:

```php
[
    ['array-1',-1],
    ['array-2', 3],
    ['array-3', 2],
    ['array-4', 0],
    ['array-5', 0]
]
```

Comment: See [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$data` has your input, you can call `usort` like this:

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    $res = ($b[1] < 0) - ($a[1] < 0);
    $diff = abs($b[1]) - abs($a[1]);
    return $res ? $res : ($diff > 0) - ($diff < 0);
});
```

After this has executed, `$data` will have the desired order.

Comment: not working for numbers less than 1 and greater than 0 like 0.5

Comment: Oh you have fractional numbers... see update.

Answer (score 1):

Sort by negatives first, then sort by absolute value descending.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hmUVn))

```
usort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) => [$b[1] < 0, abs($b[1])]
                  <=>
                  [$a[1] < 0, abs($a[1])]
);
```

Or separate the `abs()` calls as a second/fallback evaluation: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9qXnA))

```
usort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) => ($b[1] < 0 <=> $a[1] < 0)
                  ?: (abs($b[1]) <=> abs($a[1]))
);
```

Perhaps more efficient but less concise would be to isolate absolute values by calling `abs()` on each value only once.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GXbZ3))

```
$notNegs = [];
$absVals = [];
foreach ($array as [1 => $v]) {
    $abs = abs($v);
    $absVals[] = $abs;
    $notNegs[] = $v === $abs;
}
array_multisort($notNegs, $absVals, SORT_DESC, $array);
```